# Input type "number" with min and max option for Magento 1.8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento-1.8

I'm new to Magento and PHP as a whole but I want to set the `custom option` for an `input field` to

- `type= "number"`,
- define the `min` and `max` number that can be allowed in the field and
- throw an error if the the number is outside the `min` and `max` (preferably JavaScript)

However, the default custom option for input only has: [the screenshot of the input type options available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMjny.png)

Please, How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input  type="number" id="qinput-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" data-link="<?php echo $this->getAjaxUpdateUrl() ?>" data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" class="qty cart-item-quantity input-text input_qty" name="" min="1" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" />
```

This is an example of minicart input field with min=1, you can also set max for it. You don't even have to use js in this as it won't take value less than 1.

Comment: Thanks, but where those this snippet of code goes into?

Comment: Please put the screenshot of the complete screen for our better understanding.